# Evaluate line integral for a vector field

Tags: definite-integrals, vector-fields, line-integrals, cylindrical-coordinates

> Given the vector field $\mathbf{E}=\mathbf{a_x}y+\mathbf{a_y}x$, evaluate $\int\mathbf{E} \cdot \text{d}l$ from $P_3(3,4,-1)$ to $P_4(4,-3,-1)$ by converting both $\mathbf{E}$ and $P_3$ and $P_4$ into cylindrical coordinates: -

**My attempt**

Converting $\mathbf{E}$ to cylindrical coordinates should be: $\mathbf{E} = \mathbf{a_r}r\sin(\phi) + \mathbf{a_\phi}r\cos(\phi)$.

Converting the points to cylindrical should be using $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\phi = \arctan(\frac{y}{x})$:

$P_3(5, 53.13^\circ, -1) \: \: $ and $\: \: P_4(5, -36.9^\circ, -1)$

We calculate the dot product: $\mathbf{E} \cdot \text{d}l = r\sin(\phi)\text{d}r + r^2\cos(\phi)\text{d}\phi$

Finally we integrate:
$$\int_{53.13^\circ}^{-36.9^\circ}\int_5^5r\sin(\phi)\text{d}r+r^2\cos(\phi)\text{d}\phi=0 $$
And this is where I'm stuck. It can'
t be right that the result is $0$. It's that $r$ going from $5$ to $5$ that makes it all go to zero but what should I do instead? Btw, is my conversion to cylindrical coordinates correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not correct conversion. We have,
$\hat x = \cos\phi ~\hat r - \sin\phi ~ \hat \phi$
$\hat y = \sin\phi ~\hat r + \cos\phi ~ \hat \phi$

So in cylindrical coordinates, $\mathbf {E} = y ~\hat x + x ~\hat y$ will be written as,

$\mathbf{E} = r \sin2\phi ~ \hat r + r \cos 2\phi ~\hat \phi$

Points $P_3$ and $P_4$ are $(5, \arctan (4/3), -1)$ and $(5, \arctan (-3/4), -1)$ respectively.

So it is clear that both points are on curve $C$ which is a circle centered on z-axis at $z = -1$, with radius $5$. Also note that the vector field is conservative so using the scalar function $f(r, \phi)~$ whose gradient is $\mathbf{E}$, the line integral is simply $f(P_4) - f(P_3)$.

If you want to evaluate the line integral, it is easier to do so along curve $C$ from $P_3$ to $P_4$.

$ \displaystyle \int_C \mathbf{E} \cdot dl = 5 \int_{\arctan(4/3)}^{\arctan(-3/4)} \mathbf{E} \cdot \hat \phi ~ d\phi$

$ \displaystyle  = 25 \int_{\arctan(4/3)}^{\arctan(-3/4)} \cos (2\phi) ~ d\phi = -24$

Comment: Given that $\bf E$ is conservative with a comparatively simple potential in Cartesian coordinates (${\bf E} = \nabla(xy)$), it's peculiar that the problem statement insists on changing coordinates, which creates a good deal of otherwise unnecessary computation.

Comment: @TravisWillse Indeed it's peculiar! Just to get to the answer, one doesn't even need to use a pen or pencil.